# Why doesn't metadata badges track?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

I'm trying to figure out why metadata badges aren't tracked from the profile page. I have tags here with discussion 8x, I have 8 posts for discussion, and some definitely have upvotes.

[image]

But when I attempt to see the tracked progress on the discussion badge from the metadata profile page:

[image]

I can see that my progress towards the discussion badge is still 0.

Why isn't the tracking on this badge working?

Does this badge only track for answers or questions as well?

Comment: You have 8 questions and 0 answers. For the badge you need answers, not questions, so it is working perfectly.

Comment: @AndréKool so these badges don't track for question's only answers?  Interesting, if you post that as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in your own screenshot you need answers for the badge:

[image]

Because you have 8 questions and 0 answers your grand total for the badge is 0.

Comment: nice freehand :)

Answer (score 4):

The image shows the 0 score in **answers** with total posts 8 in the tag.
If you hover over 0 it will show score for questions as well:

> Asked 8 non wiki questions with a total score of 11.

If you had any answers the message would read:

> Asked 8 non wiki questions with a total score of 11. Gave x non wiki answers with a total score of y.

The tag badges in both main and meta are counted as per your score in answers.